# WebDriverWait + Dropdown size menu

Tags: python, selenium, scripting, bots, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to make a auto script bot that find a specific item and adds the item to the users cart and so forth. Right now I am caught up getting python to select the size from the dropdown menu.

I also went with the WebDriverWait function because it was giving me a element not found error , so i assumed it the 'size' element had not loaded yet.

Python is also throwing me this error

"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Below is also a picture of the html code I am referencing to pull the information from. Also will appreciate any advice on better executions.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Open chrome web browswer and directs to supreme.com

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')

#Find specific item 

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="container"]/article[14]/div/a/img').click()

#Wait for element to load 

pause = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(By.ID('size'))
)


# Select size 

Select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('size'))
Select.select_by_visible_text("Large")
```

Comment: you might need to click on the locater since the options are not enabled until the size dropdown is clicked. Also, your page's intermediate state might cause this page to fail because the article you're suggesting to buy is already sold out

Comment: So am I missing the call .click() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/article[12]/div/a/img').click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.ID,'size')))
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('size'))
select.select_by_visible_text("Medium")
```

Comment: @Ksuby syntax that you have used for visibility of elements is wrong, I corrected it. Did you tried this?

Comment: In my machine I have verified its working, hope it will works for you.